# make http call in intercept and retrun result

Tags: android, retrofit

I have this Interceptor, the idea is to call another API in interceptor

the problem is onResponse is called with the first call

```
val serivceCa = serivce.getDate("http://api.aladhan.com/v1/gToH?date=07-12-2014")
```

but I want the result from the interceptor  call

val serivceCa = serivce.getDate("http://api.aladhan.com/v1/gToH?date=07-12-2020")

```
addInterceptor (object : Interceptor {
                        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
    
                        val request= chain.request()
                        val response = chain.proceed(request)
                        val body =response.peekBody(2048)


                        val serivce = RetrofitClientInstance.buildService(Serivce::class.java)
                        val serivceCa = serivce.getDate("http://api.aladhan.com/v1/gToH?date=07-12-2020")



                        if (flag) {
                            val result = serivceCa.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
                                override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
                                    Log.d("result", "response.body().toString()")

                                }

                                override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                                    Log.d("resul222222t", response.body().toString())
                                }

                            })
                        }
                        flag=false
                    return response
                    }

                })
```

fun callAPI() {

```
  val serivce = RetrofitClientInstance.buildService(Serivce::class.java)
            val serivceCa = serivce.getDate("http://api.aladhan.com/v1/gToH?date=07-12-2014")


            val result = serivceCa.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("result", "response.body().toString()")

                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                    Log.d("result", response.body().toString())
                }

            })
             flag = true

        }
```

}

Comment: You want the response of the inner request first? Is this your question?

Comment: @AdityaKurkure yes , note when I debug "return response" is called twice than onresopnse is called but with the first not the inner